# Dell R430 Expansion Cards

Tags: windows, dell, nic, pci

I want to install a dual- or quad-port gigabit NIC card in a Dell riser card.  The full-height slot is already populated with a Dell SAS HBA (green card in the photo.)  Can I use the other side of the riser card for a half-height NIC?

The reason I'm asking is because the riser card uses the same PCI slot on the system board for both the slots on the riser card.  It doesn't seem like both the HBA and an additional NIC could make use of this single PCI slot.  Hardware needs to be purchased yet so I'm trying to make sure it will work before I buy.

Dell documentation is not specific.

Thanks for your help.

[image: Dell R430 PCIe riser card]

Comment: Yes you can. That's why that slot on the riser card exists.

Answer (score 0):

Just use an HHHL NIC. Half-height, half length. These are easy to find and are compatible with your setup